# css: transistioning from centered flex items to fixed to allow for overflow-x?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I want all the flex item card components to be centred within the parent for computer devices, however for devices that are smaller, from about 1200px and downwards I want the flex items to start overflowing the parent allowing you to horizontally scroll. I'm going to add some scroll snapping afterwards as well. I managed to get it kinda working by using a media query and setting the `justify-content` back to initial from centred, however I get no spacing on the sides.

I want the overflow to not affect the position of the left most card, so the scroll bar should be on the left most side, **not the center**

Here is some pictures of what is looks like now:

[image]
[image]

and my code => (this is using **styled components**, if you don't know it, I'll try to be as explicit as possible)

the card component:

```
export const SelectCardWrapper = styled.div`
    flex-basis: 250px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    height: 435px;
    background: #434055;
    border-radius: 25px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px rgba(0,0,0, .25);

    ${SelectCardOption} {      <== the individual options
        margin-bottom: 11.2px;
    }

    ${SelectCardOption}:last-child {
    
    }
`;
```

the card component container:

```
export const CardContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0 50px;

    ${SelectCardWrapper} { <== give the flex items a fixed gap
        margin: 20px;
    }
  

    @media (max-width: 1200px) {
       justify-content: initial; <== this was the solution, but it's not getting quite the desired effect.
    }
   

`
```

if anyone could answer in pure html and css that would be nice, I don't need it in react or styled components.

**Edit:**

still can't get this to work after hours of trying, I recreated it in code sandbox, any suggestions

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-northcutt-1ceo6?file=/style.css

Comment: use margin on the first and last element: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65580072/8620333

Comment: I already tried that, it doesn't work